# Automated Tester failing while output of of the function when called on the arrays performs correctly?

Tags: java

Im using an automated tester for the first time. I have written code to take two arrays and compare them against each other. The tester passes in some values. When i pass them n through myself it appears that i got it correct but the tester still answers as wrong. When the tester is ran it returns this:

Running testQ4_02WrongSpot

After calling

```
  int[] i0 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  Team t0 = new Team(i0);
  int[] i1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 9, 5 };
  Team t1 = new Team(i1);
  SuggestedTeam st0 = new SuggestedTeam(t0, t1);
  int i2 = st0.getNumWrongSpot();
```

expected the result of st0.getNumWrongSpot() to be 1 but got 4.

Tests failed

When it is complied it returns this:

4 4
numWrongStop: 1
1
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 4 9 5

any help would be hugely appreciated

```
class TeamDrafter {
    private Node head; // Head of the linked list for previous draft teams
    private Team solution; // Game solution

    // Public constructor
    public TeamDrafter(Team solution) {
        this.solution = solution;
        this.head = null; // Initialize the linked list as empty
    }

    // Public method to check suggested team
    public boolean checkSuggestedTeam(Team team) {
        //int[] suggestedTeamData = team.getSuggestedTeam();
        //int[] solutionTeamData = solution.getSuggestedTeam();
        SuggestedTeam suggestedTeam = new SuggestedTeam(team, solution);
    
        // Create a new Node with the SuggestedTeam and add it to the head of the linked list
        head = new Node(suggestedTeam, head);
        //System.out.println("head = "+head.toString());
        // Placeholder logic for checking if the draft team is as expected
        //return isDraftTeamEqualSolution(suggestedTeam);
        return true;
    }

    // Public getter method for previous draft teams
    public String getPreviousSuggestions() {
        Node current = head;
        if (current != null) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            while (current != null) {
                //System.out.println("W"+current.suggestedTeam);
                result.append(current.suggestedTeam).append("\n");
                current = current.next;
            }
            return result.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Public getter method for the game solution
    public Team getSolution() {
        return solution;
    }
/*
    // Override toString method to display a string representation of the list
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            result.append(current.suggestedTeam.toString()).append("\n");
            current = current.next;
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
*/

    // Placeholder for the Team class (implement according to your logic)

    // Placeholder for the SuggestedTeam class (implement according to your logic)
    private static class SuggestedTeam {
            private Team suggestion;
            private Team solution;
        
            // Public constructor that takes two Team arguments
            public SuggestedTeam(Team suggestion, Team solution) {
                this.suggestion = suggestion;
                this.solution = solution;
            }
        
            public Team getTeam() {
                return suggestion;
            }
        
            public Team getSolution() {
                return solution;
            }
        
            public int getNumGood() {
                int goodNum = 0;
        
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (suggestion.getPlayer(i) == solution.getPlayer(i)){
                        goodNum++;
                    }
                }
                return goodNum;
            }
        
            public int getNumWrongSpot() {
                int numWrongStop = 0;
                
                // index of guess
                for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
                    // index of solution
                    for (int x =0; x < 5; x++) {
                        if(x != i){
                            if(solution.getPlayer(i) == suggestion.getPlayer(x)) {
                                System.out.println(solution.getPlayer(i) + " " + suggestion.getPlayer(x));
                                numWrongStop++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("numWrongStop: "+numWrongStop);
                return numWrongStop;
            }
        
          public String toString() {
              StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
              for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                  result.append(suggestion.getPlayer(i));
                  if (i < 5 - 1)
                      result.append(" ");
              }
              return result.toString() + (" (Good " + getNumGood() + ", Wrong spot " + (getNumWrongSpot() - getNumGood()) + ")");
          }
        
    }

    // Placeholder for the Node class
    private static class Node {
        private SuggestedTeam suggestedTeam;
        private Node next;

        public Node(SuggestedTeam suggestedTeam, Node next) {
            this.suggestedTeam = suggestedTeam;
            this.next = next;
        }

        // Implement any methods or logic needed for Node
    }
    /*private static class Node {
        private SuggestedTeam suggestedTeam;
        private Node next;

        public Node(SuggestedTeam suggestedTeam) {
            this.suggestedTeam = suggestedTeam;
            this.next = next;
        }

        // Implement any methods or logic needed for Node
    }*/
/*
    // Placeholder for the comparison logic
    private boolean isDraftTeamEqualSolution(SuggestedTeam draftTeam) {
        // Implement your actual logic for comparing the draft team with the solution
        // Return true if the draft team is equal to the solution, otherwise false
        return true;//java.util.Arrays.equals(draftTeam.getTeamData(), solution.getSuggestedTeam());
    }
*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] i0 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Team t0 = new Team(i0);
        int[] i1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 9, 5 };
        Team t1 = new Team(i1);
        SuggestedTeam st0 = new SuggestedTeam(t0, t1);
        System.out.println(st0.getNumWrongSpot());
        System.out.println(t0);
        System.out.println(t1);
    }
}

//
    class Team {
        // Array of players
        private int[] players;

        // Public constructor that takes a single int array argument to initialize the team
        public Team(int[] players) {
            this.players = players;
        }

        // 
        public int getPlayer(int i) {
            return players[i];
        }

        //
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(""); 
            for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                result.append(players[i]);
                if (i < players.length - 1)
                    result.append(" ");
            }
            return result.toString();
        }

        // Implement according to your actual logic
        public int[] getSuggestedTeam() {
            // Implement according to your actual logic
            return players;
        }
    }
```